# How can i router-link to child components by name Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can i router-link to child components by name

My router

```js
  {
    path: '/guild/:guildId',
    name: 'Guild',
    component: Guild,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'overview',
        name: 'Guild.OverView',
        component: Index
      }
    ]
  }
```

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'Guild.OverView', params: {guildId: guildId} }">Overview</router-link>
```

it's worked but, if link in the nest, the link will nested each click

like bellow

```
http://localhost/guild/0/
http://localhost/guild/0/overview
http://localhost/guild/0/overview/overview
http://localhost/guild/0/overview/overview/overview
```

i want:

```
http://localhost/guild/0/
http://localhost/guild/0/overview
http://localhost/guild/0/overview
http://localhost/guild/0/overview
```

sorry for my bad english

Please could someone help me?

I'm making a sidebar that will be displayed in the child route
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5jX0.png)

Comment: I noticed that you didn't specify the params in router-link to attribute.

{name: 'Guild.OverView', params: {guildId: 'someId'}}

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you specify your question in more detail?

Comment: i have set the parameter, but my route still loops

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your problem, I think your problem will be solved if you try this.

```
 <router-link :to="'/guild/'+ guildId +'/overview'"></router-link>
```

In the data part, define the parameter guildId,

```
data() {
return {
  guildId: 0,
};
```

},

Right now you can just change the x parameter and go wherever you want and there will be no nested.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: it will works for now. thank you for your time and help